# Powershell ISE freezes while killing process

Tags: windows, maven, powershell, powershell-ise

I've ran into a few cases where powershell ISE will freeze when you try to kill a process with Ctrl+C. I can still move my cursor around the console but the status is stuck on "Stopping".

This has happened for several commands but one particular command I've noticed this consistently happening for is

```
mvn jasmine:bdd
```

This command runs a maven plugin which starts a jetty server. I can stop this with Ctrl+C from Powershell Console but not from Powershell ISE. Could this be related to the fact that Powershell ISE can't run interactive commands?

Right now my workaround is to just "start" maven in another process. Anyone else run into a similar problem?

Thanks

Comment: I've had similar issues with ISE, but not on a single specific process like this. My issues have always been intermittent.

Comment: I had same problem for many tasks like ant-building, running webservers or similar java applications. It always freezes at Stopping.

Comment: I also had similar issues. I had to restart PowerShell ISE for resolving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened case for Powershell team while referencing this issue.

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7970

Seems like recommended way is to use VS Code with Powershell.

Also this can help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/vscode/using-vscode?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly write the script to capture <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> as input. Found an [circa 2014 post on Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/35664978-2244-4a16-8059-fc1fe218241a/powershell-ise-ctrlcbreak-on-java-processes-maven?forum=winserverpowershell) that seems to address a very similar phenomenon. Cannot speak the validity of the 'answer', but one of the links in the thread will take you down a bit of a rabbit-hole of other links with possible workarounds.